# OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363 python Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, openai-gym

guys, I've spent the past couple days trying to fix this error but nothing is working I can't really find what it means online either it's happening in spyder when I'm trying to give the environment an action_space

```
 def __init__(self, full_action_space = False):
    master = None
    game='pong'
    obs_type='ram'
    frameskip=(2, 5)
    repeat_action_probability=0
    full_action_space=True
    self.master = master        

    self.ale = atari_py.ALEInterface()

    # Tune (or disable) ALE's action repeat:
    # https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/349
    assert isinstance(repeat_action_probability, (float, int)), \
            "Invalid repeat_action_probability: {!r}".format(repeat_action_probability)
    self.ale.setFloat(
            'repeat_action_probability'.encode('utf-8'),
            repeat_action_probability)

    #self.seed()
    if full_action_space:
       self._action_set = self.ale.getLegalActionSet() 
    else: 
       self._action_set = self.ale.getMinimalActionSet()
    self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(len(self._action_set))
```

The bottom parts are the parts causing it getLegalActionSet() and getMinimalActionSet() as removing them makes the file run on its own but doesn't run any training at all. I'm not sure if I have just not passed something I should have or if its a file problem.